# 2 Level pivot using Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, pivot-table, crosstab, postgres-crosstab

I have a table whose schema along with data (table_name : raw_data) appears to be this :

```
name | category | clear_date |

A    | GOOD     | 2020-05-30 |
A    | GOOD     | 2020-05-30 |
A    | GOOD     | 2020-05-30 |
A    | GOOD     | 2020-05-30 |
A    | BAD      | 2020-05-30 |
A    | BAD      | 2020-05-30 |
```

Now if I perform a "groupby" operation using the following statement :

```
 SELECT name, category, date(clear_date), count(clear_date)
 FROM raw_data
 GROUP BY name, category, date(clear_date)
 ORDER BY name
```

I get the following answer :

```
  name | caetgory | date      | count |
  A    | GOOD     |2020-05-30 |  4    |
  A    | BAD      |2020-05-30 |  1    |
  A    | BAD      |2020-05-31 |  1    |
```

IN order to produce the pivot in following format :

```
 name | category | 2020-05-30 | 2020-05-31 |
 A    | GOOD     | 4          |   NULL     | 
 A    | BAD      | 1          |   1        |
```

I am using the following query :

```
 select * from crosstab (
    'select name, category, date(clear_date), count(clear_date) from raw_data group by name, category, date(clear_date) order by 1,2,3',
    'select distinct date(clear_date) from raw_data order by 1'
    )
    as newtable (
    node_name varchar, alarm_name varchar, "2020-05-30" integer, "2020-05-31" integer
)
ORDER BY name
```

But I am getting results as follows :

```
    name | category | 2020-05-30 | 2020-05-31 |
    A    | BAD      |    4       | 1          |
```

Can anyone please try to suggest how can i achieve the result mentioned above. It appears crosstab removes the duplicate entry of A automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is possible using `crosstab` because you have a missing records in some dates. Here is an example how to get expected result but not sure is what you need. Anyway hope this helps.

```
SELECT r1.*, r2.counter AS "2020-05-30", r3.counter AS "2020-05-31"
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT name, category
    FROM raw_data
) AS r1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT name, category, count(*) AS counter
      FROM raw_data
     WHERE clear_date = '2020-05-30'
     GROUP BY name, category
) AS r2 ON (r2.category = r1.category AND r2.name = r1.name)
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT name, category, count(*) AS counter
      FROM raw_data
     WHERE clear_date = '2020-05-31'
     GROUP BY name, category
) AS r3 ON (r3.category = r1.category AND r3.name = r1.name)
ORDER BY r1.category DESC;
```